# Google analytics>ACQUISITION>channels>display

Tags: google-analytics

Do you know what type of source is the **display**?
I have never seen it before.

[image: Google analytucs screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display refers to Medium matches regex `^(display|cpm|banner)$` or Ad Distribution Network exactly matches Content.

Anything related display format. Or you can say Formats OR types of Ad display Network.